# Create Custom Field in OpenCart 2.0

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I am new to OpenCart and I would like to know how to add a custom field (a textarea with `WYSIWYG` editor enabled) in OpenCart back-end (in Product section) and then echo it to front-end (`product.tpl`).

I've followed this [tutorial](http://www.php-dev-zone.com/2015/01/how-to-add-custom-product-field-in.html) & successful created the custom field in backend admin panel but couldn't echo it to frontend.

Comment: Please clear all cache both vqmod (if You're using it) and opencart cache or changes may not appear.

Answer (score 2):

**Hi, I found this tutorial which is compatible with Opencart 2.0:**

http://www.php-dev-zone.com/2015/01/how-to-add-custom-product-field-in.html

**Please refrain from overwriting core files and use vqmod instead:**

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=19501

> I would advise you to use the tutorial and write everything into the
>   actual core files first to see if it works (which seems correct) and
>   then do it the proper way and move it all to vqmod.

**In: /catalog/controller/product/product.php**

**You'll find things like:**

```
$data['description'] = html_entity_decode($product_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

If you add your field there, eg:

```
$data['custom_desc'] = $product_info['custom_desc'];
```

**Then on the frontend you will be able to echo it into**

/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl

**as**

```
$custom_desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've already followed the URL you've provided and successfully created the custom field but the tutorial doesn't show how to echo them to frontend.

Comment: I'm seeing this error `Notice: Undefined variable: custom_desc in C:\wamp\www\Dazzle_OpenCart\catalog\view\theme\dazzle\template\product\product.tpl on line 330`

Comment: Please make sure to clear cache after each modification (just in case)

Comment: You may also need to add it to $data['products'][] = array(..
And try echoing as $product['custom_desc'];

Comment: there is an array $data['products'] in the controller, you need to add your custom field into it and then echo on the front-end as $product['custom_field']

Comment: Also, please make sure you are using the correct controller. If your view is product.tpl then use controller product.php etc.

Comment: @CrtvcaMag : next part of the article for displaying the custom product field in front end has been published. Please check the link given at the bottom of this mentioned article.

Comment: @CLECode : If we want to use vqmod then we must know very well how vqmod works, as it has issues with cache and version compatibility. Sometimes minor mistake in vqmod file can completely whitewash your application. Changes in files are easy for anyone. you just need to make sure that you applied all the changes at correct places. So I wrote article on file changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
open admin\model\catalog\product.php

Find addProducts($data) 
function and add below code just after 
`sort_order`
and before     
date_added = NOW()");
your_desc = '" . $this->db->escape($data['your_desc']) . "',

Now find 
editProduct($product_id, $data)` function and add below code just after sort_order and before date_modified = NOW()
your_desc = '" . $this->db->escape($data['your_desc']) . "',

Now open admin\controller\catalog\product.php
Find getForm() function and add below code:

$data['entry_your_desc'] = $this->language->get('entry_your_desc');

Find below code 
if (isset($this->request->post['isbn'])) {
        $data['isbn'] = $this->request->post['isbn'];
    } elseif (!empty($product_info)) {
        $data['isbn'] = $product_info['isbn'];
    } else {
        $data['isbn'] = '';
    }

and add your code just after it

if (isset($this->request->post['your_desc'])) {
 $data['your_desc'] = $this->request->post['your_desc'];
} elseif (isset($product_info)) {
$data['your_desc'] = $product_info['your_desc'];
} else {
$data['your_desc'] = '';
}

Open catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\product.tpl
and find the below code:

<li><?php echo $text_stock; ?> <?php echo $stock; ?></li>
Now add your code after it:
 <li><?php echo $text_your_desc; ?> <?php echo $your_desc; ?></li>
You can place wherever you want to.

Open catalog\language\english\product\product.php
and add your piece of code:

$_['text_your_desc']               = 'Your_description';

Open catalog\controller\product\product.php
Find:

$data['heading_title'] = $product_info['name'];
and add:

$data['text_your_desc'] = $this->language->get('text_your_desc');

Scroll down and find

$data['product_id'] = (int)$this->request->get['product_id'];

now add:

$data['your_desc'] = $product_info['your_desc'];

Open admin\view\template\catalog\product_form.tpl
Find:

<div class="tab-pane" id="tab-data">

Now add your code:

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-your_desc">
<?php echo $entry_your_desc; ?>
</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="your_desc" value="<?php echo $your_desc; ?>"      placeholder="<?php echo $entry_your_desc; ?>" id="input-your_desc" class="form- control" />
</div>
</div>

Open catalog\model\catalog\product.php
Find:

if ($query->num_rows) {
and add your code:

'your_desc'            => $query->row['your_desc'],

Open admin\language\english\catalog\product.php
Find :

//Entry
and add :

$_['entry_your_desc']      = 'Your_description';
```